# Protocol delegate not giving desired result

Tags: ios, swift

A simple profile page with an image to display based on what i select on the settings page, different files for controller and view, click on tick of profile go to settings page, select image1 or image2 and that image must display on profile page ,i try and create a protocol on settings to be able to add image , then implement a delegate on profile view file so that it can update the image its not working, can any one please point out my error

SettingsController

```
import UIKit

protocol ShowImage: class {
    func displayImage(_ of: UIImage)
}

class SettingsController: UIViewController {
   
    weak var delegate: ShowImage?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
      
        let settings = SettingsView()
        view.addSubview(settings.view)
        settings.btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dCode), for: .touchUpInside)
      

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    
   
    
    @objc func dCode() {
       
        let image = UIImage(named: "homei")
        delegate?.displayImage(image!)
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ProfileController(), animated: true)
    }
    
    
   
     
    
    
   
}
```

SettingsView

```
import UIKit

class SettingsView: UIViewController {
    
    var btn1 = UIButton()
       var btn2 = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        btn1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
              btn1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        btn1.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
              btn2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
              btn2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
              btn2.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
                     btn2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
              btn1.setTitle("Image1", for: .normal)
              btn2.setTitle("Image2", for: .normal)
              
              let stackP = UIStackView()
              
              stackP.axis = .horizontal
              stackP.alignment = .top
              stackP.spacing = 10
              stackP.distribution = .fill
              
              stackP.addArrangedSubview(btn1)
              stackP.addArrangedSubview(btn2)
              stackP.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              
              view.addSubview(stackP)
              
              stackP.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
              stackP.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
              
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

}
```

Profile Controller

```
import UIKit

class ProfileController: UIViewController {
   
    
 let profile = ProfileView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        view.addSubview(profile.view)
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        profile.settingsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotoSettings), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
  
    
    @objc func gotoSettings(){
        let settings = SettingsController()
  
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(settings, animated: true)
    }
    
   

}
```

Profile View

```
import UIKit

class ProfileView: UIViewController, ShowImage{
    func displayImage(_ of: UIImage) {
        apply(img: of)
    }
    
    
    

    var bgImage = UIImageView()
    var settingsBtn = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        bgImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bgImage)
        bgImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        bgImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        
        
        settingsBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        settingsBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
       // settingsBtn.setTitle("Settings", for: .normal)
        settingsBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick"), for: .normal)
        settingsBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        settingsBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.addSubview(settingsBtn)
        settingsBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        settingsBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
        settingsBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 70).isActive = true
        
        let set = SettingsController()
        set.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func apply(img: UIImage)
    {
        bgImage.image = img
    }
    
   
    

}
```

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be aware that the created instances of `SettingsController()` in `ProfileController` and `ProfileView` are different. And in the latter you create the instance, set the delegate and then throw it away.

Comment: @vadian , thanks so , if i click button one and select an image , how can i make it appear on profile page, which is blank, should i make the view of profile or controller of profile the delegate

Comment: Obviously you don't use storyboard, so you are responsible for maintaining the life cycle – and the references – of the views.

Comment: @vadian, thanks, so i was wondering if this protocol delegate can be helpful if i want some thing to happen in viewDidLoad as in profile view file that is where i need to make the delegation happen but how can i do that ?

Comment: Protocol/delegate is useful if the objects are related to each other in the view hierarchy and you have the (strong) references to both.

Comment: @vadian can you recommend any source for reading this , apple documentation has got me all confused

Comment: I'm afraid, no, Apple recommends to use storyboard and so do I

Comment: @vadian so should i use story boards in all projects as team sharing is an issue as suggested by many ?

Comment: My recommendation is in general. I don't know your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let set = SettingsController()
set.delegate = self
```

You're making a brand new `SettingsController`, setting its delegate... and then doing nothing with it. You probably want to find the existing `SettingsController` that is on the screen, though you have a very confusing system here with `xView` and `xController`, both of which are view controllers, so it's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: @jrtutton,thanks, yes even i am confused how this thing works, can you please suggest if my approach of creating a protocol in settings and adopting in profile view is correct, the problem is for the image to appear some how the bgImage.image has to happen in viewDidLoad, how can i do that ?